# How to receive the file when connecting success in TURNSocket Of XMPPFramework in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, file, xmpp

I want to use `TURNSocket` to transfer the file between the two users.

User1: (iphone sumulator)
User2: (Spark user)

Now the socket has connected, and i want to send a file to User1 from User2 via the Spark. And the iphone sumulator can received these message:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="P1J6b-29" to="User1@local/75694fce" from="User2@local/Spark 2.6.3"     type="set">
  <si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="jsi_8334411215933911079" mime-type="image/png"
      profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer">
    <file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="a2.png" size="12618">
      <desc>Sending file</desc>
    </file>
    <feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg">
      <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
        <field var="stream-method" type="list-single">
          <option>
            <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value>
          </option>
          <option>
            <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value>
          </option>
        </field>
      </x>
    </feature>
  </si>
</iq>
```

I saw these in the [XMPP Sending/Receving file in iphone sdk ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328553/xmpp-sending-receving-file-in-iphone-sdk)
topic about how to handle in `didSucceed` method, but i don't know how to receive the file that was sent by Spark user on the iphone sumulator.

Then, in your `didSucceed` implementation, send data on the socket that was passed in, using:

```
- (void)writeData:(NSData *)data 
  withTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout 
          tag:(long)tag;
```

Finally, close the socket:

```
- (void)disconnectAfterWriting;
```

So how to code to receive the file in this method or others?

```
- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {
    // Where is the NSData that can be find to used in writeData method ?
}
```

Comment: Hi Neil, did you get this thing working?

Answer (score 1):

Try FastSocket https://github.com/dreese/fast-socket. It is best for TCP connection between either iPhones or servers. Please read the docs as well (especially the Unit Tests) for a very detailed instruction on how to use it. You will need to know the IP's of each of the devices that are needed to connect to each other.