# send files to MUC Rooms using XMPP Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

How to send files to MUC Rooms using XMPP Framework?
I have searched a lot about this.

Using the SI method i get error `503 service unavailable or Wrong JID` ,but how to pass a resource for groupchat ?

I had used the method to transfer image using string data but now its not up to my needs. I read that we can upload file to server and send the link instead. I'm using openfire server.

If anybody has some insight about this please share. Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can upload your image to a server and send the link.
The flow goes like this:

You need to send a thumbnail image using xmpp (and the link of the original image stored on server), like you must be sending the entire image now in your application.

When the user clicks on the thumbnail image, you can download the original image from the server using that link.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Okay so how can i upload images to openfire ? It has an embedded DB. Do i have to migrate it to mysql or is there some other way ?

Comment: @skywalker6131 :
I personally recommend using mysql db instead of embedded db, however you can carry on with your current structure. If you are willing to use the mysql db refer http://mindbowser.com/blog/openfire-installation-and-database-configuration/ for database configuration of openfire

You can get the code implementation help from these 2 links:
1. https://kashiftriffort.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/xmpp-how-to-send-message-with-image-using-xmpp-in-iphone/

2.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524475/sending-image-using-xmpp-framework-on-iphone

Comment: Thanks for the links,I'm currently using the base 64 method only. But the thing is that the image takes time to come. Now I just want to upload the image to Open-fire and send url ,so that other user can download it by himself/herself. So for that i need some reference on how  to upload image to open-fire.

Comment: I will appreciate if you up-vote my answer and I'll try to assist you further. What do you mean by uploading the image to openfire? Do you mean to save in the embedded db? or sending as attachement?

Comment: I tried upvoting it but i need 15 rep so that my upvote can be visible and I'm at 11 so sorry about that. Yes save it in embedded DB. I'm already sending it as an attachment but that makes the xml request too big and due to that even during receiving i'm facing the same delay. I would rather have it to upload the image and send URL to other user. So i can place a placeholder for that image.

Comment: Sending a placeholder instead of thumbnail is a bad practice, however you want to upload the image and send its link then we'll discuss on it.
You need to upload the image on Amazon aws's s3 bucket and you'll get its link. You can then simply save this in your db.
Refer http://mindbowser.com/blog/how-to-integrate-amazon-apis-using-amazon-ios-sdk/
This will guide you from setting s3 till uploading image on s3.

Comment: okay so like there is no way to upload it on open-fire ? Also i have a custom placeholder so that's I'm using it but thanks i'll remember it for future references.